# vba code to only highlight contiguous duplicates in one column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which highlights contiguous and non-contiguous cells that have the same contents in a single column with different colours. Could this code be modified to highlight **only** contiguous cells in one column with one colour (e.g. yellow)?

```
Sub HighlightSameValues()
Dim rngArea As Range
Dim rngCellA As Range
Dim rngCellB As Range
Dim colValue As New Collection
Dim intColor As Integer  
Set rngArea = ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F65536")
intColor = 5
On Error Resume Next
For Each rngCellA In rngArea
If rngCellA.Value <> "" Then
Err.Clear
colValue.Add rngCellA.Value, "MB" & rngCellA.Value
If Err = 0 Then
intColor = intColor + 1
For Each rngCellB In rngArea
If rngCellB.Value = rngCellA.Value Then
rngCellB.Interior.ColorIndex = intColor
End If
Next rngCellB
End If
End If
Next rngCellA
End Sub
```

Assistance with this matter is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will highlight all non-blank and duplicate values for all cells in columns B through F:

```
Sub HighlightSameValues()
Dim rngArea As Range
Dim rngCellA As Range
Dim rngCellB As Range

    'Narrow the search area to only that which has been used
    Set rngArea = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("B:F"))

    For Each rngCellA In rngArea

        'No point in searching for blank cells or ones that have already been highlighted
        If Not rngCellA.Value = vbNullString And Not rngCellA.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then

            Set rngCellB = rngArea.Find(What:=rngCellA.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=rngCellA)

            'Check if the value in rngCellA exists anywhere else
            If Not rngCellB Is Nothing And Not rngCellB.Address = rngCellA.Address Then

                'If another does exist, highlight it and every value that duplicates it
                rngCellA.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Do While Not rngCellB.Address = rngCellA.Address
                    rngCellB.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Set rngCellB = rngArea.Find(What:=rngCellA.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=rngCellB)
                Loop

            End If
        End If
    Next rngCellA
End Sub
```

To only evaluate contiguous cells in the same column I would modify the code as such:

```
Sub HighlightSameValues()
Dim rngArea As Range
Dim rngCellA As Range

    'Narrow the search area to only that which has been used
    Set rngArea = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("B:F"))

    For Each rngCellA In rngArea

        'No point in searching for blank cells or ones that have already been highlighted
        If Not rngCellA.Value = vbNullString And Not rngCellA.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            If rngCellA.Offset(-1, 0).Value = rngCellA.Value Then
                rngCellA.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                rngCellA.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
            If rngCellA.Offset(1, 0).Value = rngCellA.Value Then
                rngCellA.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                rngCellA.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        End If
    Next rngCellA
End Sub
```

This is what coding at 2am gets you with no sleep. =)

I was missing the all important Not in (Not rngCellA.Interior.Color = vbYellow). Also I noticed that I forgot to highlight the first cell identified.

I have retested both code segments and both are now working as intended.

Segment 1 will highlight anything that is duplicated within columns B through F.

Segment 2 will highlight anything that is duplicated only that is contiguous and in the same column.

If your data table starts in row 1 (No header) or goes to the last row available on the sheet:

```
If Not rngCellA.Row = 1 Then
    If rngCellA.Offset(-1, 0).Value = rngCellA.Value Then
        rngCellA.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        rngCellA.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
End If
If Not rngCellA.Row = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then
    If rngCellA.Offset(1, 0).Value = rngCellA.Value Then
        rngCellA.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        rngCellA.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks very much Dustin for your invaluable input. As I ran the first code, it highlighted the entire data regardless of being the same content or not. As for the second code, which is the aim from my question, it did not cause any change. I modified the range to be one column only, but still no detecting or highlighting for the same contents of contiguous cells. The code ran smoothly and "silently" without causing any change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Dustin, running the second code it actually stops with run-time error '1004' Application-defined or Object-defined error at this line: aIf rngCellA.Offset(-1, 0).Value = rngCellA.Value Then - any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Dustin for all your efforts, working find as expected. All the best.